# Does GitLab support PSD previews as GitHub does?

Tags: git, version-control, photoshop, gitlab

I'm wondering if GitLab now also supports previewing PSD files as GitHub does. Unfortunately I didn't find anything on this and I don't have a running instance of GitLab yet. Maybe someone who uses GitLab already can bring some light into the dark :-)

The background is that I'm still looking for a good solution for our designers to easily keep track of their versions.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't see that feature ([GitHub PDS viewing and diff'ing](https://github.com/blog/1845-psd-viewing-diffing)) in:

- any of the [GitHub GitLab repo issues](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/search?q=psd&ref=cmdform&type=Issues)
- any of the [gitlab-ce issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&issue_search=psd&state=opened&scope=all&assignee_id=&milestone_id=&label_id=)
- any of [the feedbacks](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general?query=psd): you can enter one there in order to bring support for that feature.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm, GitLab doesn't support this feature yet.